Unable to use Soulmachines's Widget snippet
I am using soulmachines for creating digital avatars.
I have created a project and an api key as per their docs.
Below is the code snippet they have provided:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>SM Widget Example</title>
  <script 
    src="https://static.soulmachines.com/widget-snippet-1.11.0.min.js" 
    data-sm-api-key= ***my api key*** 
    data-sm-position="bottomRight" 
    data-sm-greeting="Welcome" 
    data-sm-layout="fullFrame" 
    data-sm-profile- 
      picture="https://assets.cdn.soulmachines.cloud/AvatarCoverImages/image-sam-l.jpg"
    >
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

When I run the code, the digital avatar shows up.
But when I click the digital avatar, I'm getting the error:
Access to fetch at ‘https://dh.soulmachines.cloud/api/jwt' from origin ‘null’ has been blocked by CORS policy: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request’s mode to ‘no-cors’ to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

And:
GET https://dh.soulmachines.cloud/api/jwt net::ERR_FAIILED 403 (Forbidden)

I am 100% sure that my api key is valid one because am using the same api to get the digital avatar using scene.connect() and it is working fine.
But when I use it in widget snippet, I'm not getting it.
Could anyone who has some experience, working with soulmachines, help me to resolve this?

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.

What's the value of JSON.parse(atob("***my API key***")).authServer?
